# C++ Chess table BGI graphics

Tags: c++, loops, graphics, chess, bgi

I know it's pretty amateur, but I got a task of drawing a 8x8 chess table with the usual "A B C..." "1 2 3" text on the side. I have to use 2 for loops, but I'm quite stuck, I can only display one row with 8 bars, here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
#include<graphics.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j=0;
    int upperline=50;
    int widthline=50;
    double godown=500/8;
    double goright=700/8;

    initwindow(800,600,"Chessboard");
    setbkcolor(LIGHTGRAY);
    cleardevice();
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<8;j++)
            {
                if(i % 2==0) setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL,BLACK);
                else setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL,WHITE);
                bar(widthline,upperline,widthline+goright,upperline+godown);
                outtextxy(widthline+goright/2-5,upperline/2,"A");
                outtextxy(widthline+goright/2-5,600-upperline/2,"B");
            }
            widthline=widthline+goright;
        }
    getch();
    closegraph();
}
```

I'm using CodeBlocks by the way. Any kind of help is welcomed, just keep it simple. :)
Cheers

Comment: You don't say what you are stuck with, but one thing with a chess board is that the coloring is different not just for even and odd columns, but also for even and odd rows. So you need not only `i % 2` but also `j % 2` to select the proper fillstyle.

Comment: Actually I'm stuck with that it should draw 64 bars shouldn't it? And it only does 8. Indeed I need that j%2, thanks @BoPersson

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following board

```
W B W B W B W B
B W B W B W B W
W B W B W B W B
B W B W B W B W
W B W B W B W B
B W B W B W B W
W B W B W B W B
B W B W B W B W
```

This is what you want, but now consider this one:

```
  H G F E D C B A
 -----------------
1|W B W B W B W B|1
2|B W B W B W B W|2
3|W B W B W B W B|3
4|B W B W B W B W|4
5|W B W B W B W B|5
6|B W B W B W B W|6
7|W B W B W B W B|7
8|B W B W B W B W|8
 -----------------
  H G F E D C B A
```

Do you have an idea of how to do it now?

If not, read below.

You need two loops for this, one for rows and one for columns. You got that part right. Next, you need to make the following observation:

- All even rows have the 'White' cell start first, whereas all odd rows have the 'Black' cell start first. (Even as in row number - 1 is even, I started from 0. Habits :P)

If you can make this, it's easy to see how your loops should have their conditions set. (row % 2 and col % 2 should give you an idea) The next is pretty simple to see, but I'll state it anyway:

- The 0th row has 1 next to it, but 0th column has H associated with it. (I think that's how the board is meant to be, but you can fix it easily if not) So, you see now that you need to have some sort of an extra drawing process, or you can be clever and offset your loops by 2. (Why 2? Think of the symmetry of the board) Now, if you think a bit you can figure out how you can handle the loops with an offset of 2. If you can't figure it out, you can always use extra draw functions outside the loops, after all you use graphics and you are not limited to just '\n' and it's print order :p

Sample code:

```
void Grid::display_top() const {
    uint widthmax = width << 1;
    cout << "  ";
    for (uint i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (uint j = 0; j < widthmax; ++j) {
            if (!i) {
                if (!(j % 2))
                    cout << ' ';
                else
                    cout << (j >> 1);
            }
            else {
                if (!j)
                    cout << " *-";
                else if (j == widthmax - 1)
                    cout << "-*";
                else
                    cout << "-";
            }
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
}

void Grid::display_bottom() const {
    uint widthmax = width << 1;
    for (uint i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        if (i)
            cout << "  ";
        for (uint j = 0; j < widthmax; ++j) {
            if (i) {
                if (!(j % 2))
                    cout << ' ';
                else
                    cout << (j >> 1);
            }
            else {
                if (!j)
                    cout << " *-";
                else if (j == widthmax - 1)
                    cout << "-*";
                else
                    cout << "-";
            }
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
}

void Grid::display(const Player& P1, const Player& P2) const {
    cout << '\n';
    display_top();
    uint scorepos = (height >> 1) - 2;
    for (uint i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        for (uint j = 0; j < width + 4; ++j) {
            if (!j || j == width + 3)
                cout << i;
            else if (j == 1 || j == width + 2)
                cout << '|';
            else {
                cout << " ";
                spots[i][j - 2].display();
            }
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
    display_bottom();
    cout << '\n';
}
```

This was for a game I made that has a similar board to yours. I'm sure you can figure out the rest from here.

Comment: Thanks. :) Altough I'm still not sure what to modify/add to my program. Can you help me with some codes, pretty please? :)) @SenselessCoder